# Циклический сдвиг элементов списка вправо

Tags: python

**Задача у меня такая:**

> Напишите программу, которая циклически сдвигает элементы массива
> вправо (например, если элементы нумеруются, начиная с нуля, то 0-й
> элемент становится 1-м, 1-й становится 2-м, ..., последний становится
> 0-м, то есть массив {3, 5, 7, 9} превращается в массив {9, 3, 5, 7}).
>
> Входные данные
> Сначала задано число N — количество элементов в массиве
> (1≤N≤35). Далее через пробел записаны N чисел — элементы массива.
> Массив состоит из целых чисел.
>
> Выходные данные
> Необходимо вывести
> массив, полученный после сдвига элементов.
>
> Пример
> Входные данные
>
> 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
>
> Выходные данные
>
> 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1

Я написал код, постаралась и вот у меня что получилось

```
mas = []
N = int(input("Количество элементов в массиве:"))
if ( N <=35 ) and ( N > 0):
    for x in range (N+1):
        mas.append(x)
        a = mas.copy()
        i = 0
        print (a, '/n')
B = int (input("На скільки елементів зробити зсув"))
if (B <=N):
    print(mas)
    while i<B:
        i+=1
        b = a.pop()
        c = a.insert(0,b)
else:
     print(a)
     print(false)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ЧТО Не так? Разве он не должен после кнопки "Ран" делать массив чтоб уходил вправо? Объясните, пожалуйста!

Comment: а вы умеете код не в качестве скрина вставлять? а давайте я вам ответ в виде arj предоставлю?

Comment: а теперь постарайтесь еще чуть-чуть и замените в вопросе скриншоты кода его текстом, чтобы не нарушать правила сайта.

Comment: mas = []
N = int(input("Количество элементов в массиве:"))
if ( N <=35 ) and ( N > 0):
    for x in range (N+1):
        mas.append(x)
        a = mas.copy()
        i = 0
        print (a, '/n')
B = int (input("На скільки елементів зробити зсув"))
if (B <=N):
        print(mas)
        while i<B:
            i+=1
            b = a.pop()
            c = a.insert(0,b)
else:
            print(a)
            print(false)

Comment: а почему у вас в выходных данных список сдвигается влево, в не вправо?

Comment: Пока код выглядит так, как будто вы вообще не понимаете, что делаете. Хорошо бы почитать какой учебник по питону для начала.

Comment: У меня день остался до этого теста, я сам не знал что будет тест понимаете, у меня нет времени это школьные задание, я посмотрел какие нибудь видео про питон за час и т.д но там про for и про 5-2 и какие то детские задачи можете просто обьяснить?

Answer (score 1):

чтобы сделать сдвиг вправо можно использовать один из нескольких подходов:

через отрезание последнего элемента через `pop`:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

v = arr.pop()

arr.insert(0, v)
```

недостаток - для сдвига на `N` надо сделать несколько шагов

через отрезание элементов через срезы:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

arr = [arr[-1]] + arr[:-1]
```

преимущество - можно сразу сделать перемещение на `N`:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

N = 3
arr = arr[-N:] + arr[:-N]
```

Comment: это не очевидно, но подозреваю, что, поскольку сдвиг циклический, то имеет смысл добавить `N = N%len(arr)`

Comment: да, конечно надо учесть когда сдвиг происходит на расстояние, большее длине списка, я просто привел такой код потому что у автора стояла проверка на выдачу ошибки при сдвиге большем, чем размер массива